# How do I prevent unlocking the screen?

Tags: gnome, kde, screensaver, screen-lock, enlightenment

Use case: I want my screen to auto-lock when I unmount my USB drive. (That part is easy.) What's not so easy: I want the screen lock to require the USB drive *and* the password when I return.

Thus, is there a way block the screen unlock so that it only allows unlocking when some additional condition is met (test whether a file exists, for instance; I'd create that with the help of udev, that's not the problem; or run a check script and disallow unlocking unless that program exits zero)?

I'm using e17 and Gnome, but solutions for `kde/lxde/xscreensaver` are appreciated too.

Comment: That sounds like you want to look into the direction of PAM, requiring the drive as part of user authentication. Googling turns up [pamusb tutorials](http://xybrcode.com/2015/linux-authentication-with-usb-drive/), but I'm noot up-to-date on PAM to tell whether they're useful, outdated, etc.

Comment: Ahh, gnome-screensaver seems to use PAM. Great. I didn't know that. Do the others support PAM, too? (My /etc/pam.d only has entries for gnome-screensaver and xscreensaver.)